# Is it true $A\cup (B - C) = (A\cup B) - (A\cup C)$ ? additional intuition of question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I have solved the majority of this question $A\cup (B - C) = (A\cup B) - (A\cup C)$ and as well I looked at the solution that was posted previously to this question:

[Is it true that $A \cup (B - C) = (A \cup B) - (A \cup C)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348389/is-it-true-that-a-cup-b-c-a-cup-b-a-cup-c)

My question has to do with whether or not my reasoning for being able to proceed is correct. So to show that the equality was false I made up some simple sets: $A = \{0,1,2\}, B= \{2,3,4\}, C= \{1,2,5\}$.

I proceeded to get the first conclusion as false. Now the question asks whether $A\cup (B - C) \subset (A\cup B) - (A\cup C)$ or vice-versa. Now it is here where I want to know if my reasoning is correct:

So using the sets I have I got sets of different sizes (i.e cardinalities) so in the instance of $A\cup (B - C) \subset (A\cup B) - (A\cup C)$ I showed it was false, but now if we evaluate it the other way around: $(A\cup B) - (A\cup C) \subset A\cup (B - C)$ the size of the smaller set is contained within the bigger set.

Noe since the numbers I chose were random this means that I now have to prove it for the general case.

So I ask is the fact that the sets are of different sizes a correct reason as to proving $(A\cup B) - (A\cup C) \subset A\cup (B - C)$ ?

Comment: Intuition indicates that both sides equal the same set, the set of all elements that lie in $A$ or in $B$ but not in $C$

Comment: @dc3rd How could your "reasoning to prove it" be correct when you came up with simple counterexamples? This shows that your reason is certainly *not* correct.

Comment: By the way, I notice you have been a member for over 6 months, have asked over 50 questions, and yet you have never once accepted an answer (and you have only ever given 2 upvotes). That is pretty poor practice. Answerers who answer your question(s) satisfactorily should receive due acknowledgment, and choosing an answer would also let others know that your question is "effectively closed." I would recommend going back through *all* of your questions and choosing those that you deem satisfactory.

Comment: Oh. I didn't actually understand the use of the upvote system. I thought that whoever entered an answer into my questions automatically get's the respective reputation points. I was completely oblivious to the fact I needed to do that. Shoot if that's the case then yes I do need to go back and do alot of up voting. Thanks for bringing it to my attention

Comment: @dc3rd Well, I don't want to be hostile, but it is fairly important to realize that you have votes for a reason. Opinion greatly varies in terms of "what votes are for" exactly, but in general: upvote if "this answer is useful" and downvote if "this answer is not useful." The rationale for voting on questions is more or less the same (i.e., shows research effort; useful and clear, and vice-versa). I definitely do not recommend upvoting *everything* or downvoting *everything*. I'd encourage you to use your own discrimination and judgment there. But voting/accepting answers and the like...

Comment: @dc3rd ... give answerers, like I said, due acknowledgment for them taking their time to help you, and accepting an answer also indicates to others in the MSE community that you are happy with the answers you have received. I don't want to come across as snappy, and I am sorry if I did--I am glad you are aware of it all now. :)

Comment: No offense taken, it is actually important and I always questioned how do all the top posters get recognized for the hard work they're doing. sure a thank you is nice, but we're not really talking about telling people how to spell "cat" here. It is an essential part of keeping this sort of community thriving where people like me doing a bunch of self studying actually have an outlet.

Answer (score 2):

[As before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266870/set-theory-a-b-a-a-b), some simple set algebra will save you the trouble of many a headache:
\begin{align}
A\cup(B-C) &= A\cup(B\cap C^C)\tag{by definition}\\[0.5em]
&= (A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C^C)\tag{distributivity}\\[0.5em]
&\neq (A\cup B)\cap (A^C\cap C^C)\tag{observation}\\[0.5em]
&=(A\cup B)-(A\cup C).\tag{by definition}
\end{align}
To have $A\cup (B-C)=(A\cup B)-(A\cup C)$, you would need $A\cup C^C=A^C\cap C^C$, and this is clearly not true. You should be able to come up with several counterexamples fairly easily, thus disproving the alleged set identity.

Comment: Actually I hadn't notice your addition to the last problem until now. I'm going to attempt to use a bit more set algebra first. I was concerned about using set algebra because I can't remember where or whom I heard it from, but I was concerned about treating set algebra as just mechanics sort of how the simple rules of algebra are treated they become mechanical without thinking about what you're doing.

Comment: @dc3rd Are you saying set algebra is not well-defined?

Comment: good point. One of the issues I have is when I attempt to  blow through a question using set algebra and get jammed, but now referring to what you posted previously I'm going to take more into consideration when deciding if something is provable

Comment: @dc3rd As I said in my other post, I would encourage you to use set algebra whenever possible because it reduces the work you have to do considerably. Element-chasing proofs or other such approaches should come after--that is, you should resort to those proof techniques when set algebra is not getting you anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have arbitrary sets $A, B$, with $|A| \gt |B|$. This **is enough** to concluded $A\not\subseteq B$, because it is impossible for every element in $A$ to be in $B$.

However, if we have $|A| \lt |B|$, that information is ***not*** sufficient to conclude $A \subset B$.  For example, suppose $A = \{0, 2\}$ and $B = \{1, 2, 3\}$. Then we do have $|A|\lt |B|$, but $A\not\subseteq B$.

In your, you need to prove that every element in $(A\cup B) -(A\cup C)$ is also an element of $A\cup (B-C).$  That is, you need to prove

$$x\in [(A\cup B) - (A\cup C)] \rightarrow x \in [A\cup (B-C)]$$

Comment: Yes I understand what it is that I needed to prove and how, it was the cardinality argument that you presented above that I was not sure about. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

$(A\cup B)-(A\cup C)=(A\cup B)\cap(\overline{A\cup C})\stackrel{\text{DM}}=(A\cup B)\cap (\overline{A}\cap \overline{C})$

$\stackrel{\text{Distr.}}=(A\cap (\overline{A}\cap\overline{C}))\cup(B\cap(\overline{A}\cap\overline{C}))=\varnothing\cup(B\cap(\overline{A}\cap \overline{C}))$

$=B\cap(\overline{A}\cap\overline{C})=\text{RHS}$.

$x\in A\,\Rightarrow\, x\in\text{LHS}=A\cup(B-C)$, yet $x\not\in \text{RHS}$.

DM-DeMorgan, Distr-distributive property.